# Why is there such a difference between pre-render image and post-one? Could you give me some information how to handle it?

Tags: modeling

I have been trying to handle the problem with the difference between colours. In vain :) You're my last hope to do my best and keep going on in improving the skills.

[image: donut compared]

[image: donut render]

Comment: Hello. You can embed images directly in your question. This way readers have not to click the link, accept cookie agreements, click again to return to the question, and do another 3 clicks just to see the other image.

Answer (score 1):

The secret / difference is compositing. In the viewport "rendered"-view there is no compositing.

If you render your image with F12, compositing will be used.